# SqlException - deadlock with lock

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Getting error in below code:

> SqlException: Transaction (Process ID 80) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

```
    private static void CleanAbc()
    {
                using (var sql = Program.Connection())
                {
                    sql.Execute(@"
    declare @expiration datetime = DATEADD(DAY, -21, cast(GETDATE() AS DATE));

    with topfew as (select top 100000 * from abc with(paglock) 
        WHERE [time] < @expiration)
    delete topfew;

    set @expiration = DATEADD(MONTH, -6, cast(GETDATE() AS DATE));

    with topfew as (select top 100000 * from abc with(paglock) 
        WHERE [time] < @expiration)
    delete topfew;
    ", commandTimeout: 60 * 60 * 12);
                }
    }
```

Other code:

```
    public static void Start() => new Action[]
    {
        CleanAbc
    }.ToList().ForEach(clean => new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));                    
                if (IsClean())
                {
                    clean();
                }                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }).Start());

    private static bool IsClean() =>
        TimeSpan.FromHours(5) < DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
        || DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay < TimeSpan.FromHours(19);
```

Any suggestions/advice on how this can be improved?

Comment: Is this a queue? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#queues

Comment: I don't think the problem is the code, it's the SQL. Either the query you have written is very slow, and being chosen as the deadlock victim, or you have other slow queries running on the server; and this query is being chosen as the deadlock victim. I think you need to look at improving your queries performance (and that might not be the query you have here).

Comment: For a heavy `DELETE` query to be chosen as the deadlock victim, an even *more* resource-intensive query has to be running concurrently. The most likely candidate is actually the very same query you are running right now. Verify you haven't made some sort of concurrency goof where the query runs parallel with itself, or a previous running instance was never cancelled. Use Profiler to pin down what queries are running if you have to.